# If I hide bootstrap carousel, will it still be running in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap carousel with this code:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide">                    
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                    <!-- Slide -->
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">


                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item ">
                        <div class="row">
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
</div>
```

I need to disable the carousel, so I just hide it using CSS like this:

```
#slider{
    display: none;
}
```

I already commented out the init of the carousel in my main JS file:

```
//$('#slider').carousel();
```

So my question is, if I set "display:none;" and comment the JS init of the carousel, will it still run in the background? Or will it be completely disabled?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you use display: none the element exists but you can´t see it.

Comment: @zzzzBov, already made the adjustments, thank you.

Comment: @JorgeMejia correct that is true, I am wondering if it will affect the GPU or some hardware acceleration for animations still running in the background?

Comment: @Leo, that's not an MCVE because it doesn't reproduce the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Yes it will affect the GPU or some hardware acceleration because elements still in DOM and all functions and stuffs are runing by the browser, imagine you play a video, and then you add display none to the video, browser hide the video but the process still  running,but you don´t see the video. the only way to stop the proces is calling a function for stop the event or destroying the element.

Comment: @JorgeMejia Excellent, just what I needed!

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't need for you to reproduce the behavior (although you could with the code provided), is just a question about performance with the bootstrap carousel.

Comment: "I don't need for you to reproduce the behavior" without being able to exactly reproduce the behavior you're seeing it's impossible to give you accurate answers. The way in which you hide a carousel will affect its behavior, so you're mistaken in this regard.

Comment: @zzzzBov Jorge already gave me an accurate answer, many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

using `display: none` won't prevent the carousel javascript from running. In any case if you want to make sure it always starts at the first slide you could say:

```
$('#carousel').carousel(0);
```

This way the carousel will jump to the first slide.

Comment: Actually what I wanted to know is if the carousel will be completely disabled by just hiding it with "display: none;" and turning off the javascript code that initializes the carousel, or will the animations and functionality continue to run in the background?

Comment: Hiding it won't "disable" it since the javascript instantiated would still persist. So yes, the animation would continue in the background.

Comment: But then you could also make it stop if needed. Bootstrap has this buildt in the carousel. Like so: $('.carousel').carousel('pause');